# Axios not storing Django session cookie

Tags: django, vue.js, axios

I have a Django REST Framework API backend for my Vue app. I'm trying to use Django sessions for anonymous users but either Django isn't sending or Axios can't read the session cookie.

A new session is being created by checking `Session.objects.all().count()`

I'm trying to store cart data using `JWTAuthentication` for authenticated users and `SessionAuthentication` for anonymous users.

```
# settings.py

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:8080',
    '127.0.0.1:8080',
)

SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
```

I've tried toggling `SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY` in `settings.py` but still not able to see the cookie.

When intercepting the response the CSRF cookie is sent but the session cookie isn't included.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import Cookie from 'js-cookie'

axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken'
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
    const sessionCookie = Cookie.get()
    console.log('Cookie', sessionCookie)
    return response
})
```

In my DRF API tests I can see that the session cookie is in the response.

`Set-Cookie: sessionid=zgndujlppk4rnn6gymgg1czhv1u0rqfc; expires=Thu, 11 Apr 2019 11:27:32 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax`

```
class Test(APITestCase):
    def test_get(self):
        response = self.client.get('/store/1/')
        print(response.cookies['sessionid']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was I was visiting the site at the URL `localhost:8080` but the cookie was being saved under `127.0.0.1`.

Changing the URL to `127.0.0.1:8080` solved the problem.